# Stack overflow when tabbing in flash player 10

Tags: apache-flex, flash

Has anyone run into this problem? All I am doing in tabbing from one TextInput component to another.

I have reduced my TitleWindow (the container for the TextInputs) down to only these two components and I still get this error. I assumed that it had something to do with my flashplayer install, so I uninstalled and re-installed, but I still get the same behavior.

Any help/advice/best guess would be awesome, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using FlashPlayer 10 and just tried the following without any errors.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:TitleWindow>
        <mx:TextInput id="textA">

        </mx:TextInput>

        <mx:TextInput id="textB">

        </mx:TextInput>
    </mx:TitleWindow>
</mx:Application>
```

Is there anything else going on with the tabbing? Some custom code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any handlers for, say, focus events or the like on the text fields? As far as Flash is concerned, all that happens when you tab is a change of focus. Stack overflows are usually the result of recursion, so something like that would be my first guess.

Or are you saying that there's nothing in your app except for the components?